# How to open jQuery Collapsible.js from external link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am utterly lost on how to open a panel from a link coming from another page.

I am using the jQuery Collapsible.js.

I have tried simply using the `#body-section1` after the link which will take me to the panel title on the page, but will not open it.

This page has several panels (16) and links to each section throughout the site. My goal is to have the user click on a link that will take them to the relevant page and open the correct panel for them.

I have also tried: 
`link?open#body-section1`
`link?open/#body-section1`
`class="collapse-open link?aniMain/#body-section1`

and nothing is working so far.

My HTML is:

```
<div class="page_collapsible" id="body-section1">Header Title<span></span></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="aniMain">
         <p>Body text here</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript to go with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    //syntax highlighter
    hljs.tabReplace = '    ';
    hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();

    $.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(speed, easing, callback) {
        return this.animate({opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle'}, speed, easing, callback);
    };

    //collapsible management
    $('.collapsible').collapsible({
        defaultOpen: 'section1',
        cookieName: 'nav',
        speed: 'slow',
        animateOpen: function (elem, opts) { //replace the standard slideUp with custom function
            elem.next().slideFadeToggle(opts.speed);
        },
        animateClose: function (elem, opts) { //replace the standard slideDown with custom function
            elem.next().slideFadeToggle(opts.speed);
        },
        loadOpen: function (elem) { //replace the standard open state with custom function
            elem.next().show();
        },
        loadClose: function (elem, opts) { //replace the close state with custom function
            elem.next().hide();
        }
    });
    $('.page_collapsible').collapsible({
        defaultOpen: 'body_section1',
        cookieName: 'body2',
        speed: 'slow',
        animateOpen: function (elem, opts) { //replace the standard slideUp with custom function
            elem.next().slideFadeToggle(opts.speed);
        },
        animateClose: function (elem, opts) { //replace the standard slideDown with custom function
            elem.next().slideFadeToggle(opts.speed);
        },
        loadOpen: function (elem) { //replace the standard open state with custom function
            elem.next().show();
        },
        loadClose: function (elem, opts) { //replace the close state with custom function
            elem.next().hide();
        }

    });

    //assign open/close all to functions
    function openAll() {
        $('.page_collapsible').collapsible('openAll');
    }
    function closeAll() {
        $('.page_collapsible').collapsible('closeAll');
    }

    //listen for close/open all
    $('#closeAll').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        closeAll();

    });
    $('#openAll').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        openAll();
    });

});
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need javascript to execute on the page with the panels after it has been linked to.

You could do something like inspect the hash (`window.location.hash`) on page load, and open the corresponding collapsible.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //setup should happen first
    $('.page_collapsible').collapsible({
        defaultOpen: 'body_section1',
        cookieName: 'body2',
        speed: 'slow',
        animateOpen: function (elem, opts) { //replace the standard slideUp with custom function
            elem.next().slideFadeToggle(opts.speed);
        },
        animateClose: function (elem, opts) { //replace the standard slideDown with custom function
            elem.next().slideFadeToggle(opts.speed);
        },
        loadOpen: function (elem) { //replace the standard open state with custom function
            elem.next().show();
        },
        loadClose: function (elem, opts) { //replace the close state with custom function
            elem.next().hide();
        }

    });
   //open the collapsible which was targetted in the url
   $(window.location.hash).collapsible('open'); //where the hash matches the id of whichever collapsible you want to open
});
```

So if you want to link to and open the collapsible with `id="body-section1"` your link should look like `link#body-section1`

Comment: Thank you dhreg.
I added this to the top of the page where the panel list is located and completed the code with a closing ( and ;.
However, the same thing is happening when I click an external link. It will go to the page and find the correct hashmark, but will not open it. I am linking as: 
    `link#page-section1`

Comment: Could you clarify which collapsible library you are using? (link to the docs). You may have to move the hash inspection / expand code below the initialization of the collapsibles.

Comment: I do so apologize for not including this before; This link to the demo I am using is at http://www.snyderplace.com/demos/collapsible.html

http://www.snyderplace.com/demos/javascript/jquery.collapsible.js should be the correct link to the library.

Thank you ever so much.

Comment: No problem, there just happen to be a few libraries out there which look similar but have different functions. Let me know if my revised answer helps you

Comment: +1 It is working nicely. What I had to do was to change open to close. Thanks you again.